# Can not read text file in C

Tags: c, file, linked-list, file-handling

I have an assignment to create a menu program that uses a linked list to store a list of phone catalog. Here is my source code:

```
int isempty(FILE *in)
{
    return in == NULL;
}
node *makenewnode(item newitem)
{
    node *newnode = (node *) malloc(sizeof(node));
    newnode->info = newitem;
    return newnode;
}
int countlines(FILE *datain)
{
    int lines = 0;
    char string[MAX];
    while (fgets(string, MAX, datain))
        lines++;
    return lines;
}
node *push(node *listin, item newitem)
{
    node *newnode = makenewnode(newitem);
    if(listin == NULL)
    {
        newnode->next = NULL;
        listin = newnode;
    }
    else
    {
        newnode->next = listin;
        listin = newnode;
        head = listin;
    }
    cur = head;
    return head;
}
node *builldbytext(FILE *txt, int maxlines)
{
    int i = 0;
    node *result = (node *) malloc(maxlines*sizeof(node));
    item *temp = (item *) malloc(maxlines*sizeof(item));
    while(i < maxlines)
    {
        fscanf(txt, "%s %d %f %s\n", temp[i].model, &temp[i].memory, &temp[i].screen_size, temp[i].price);
        i++;
    }
    for(i = 0; i< maxlines; i++)
        result = push(result, temp[i]);
    return result;
}
void tranverse(node *listprint, int maxlines)
{
    int i = 0;
    printf("%-20s%-15s%-20s%-30s\n", "Model", "Memory (GB)", "Screen size (Inch)", "Price");
    for(i = 0; i < maxlines; i++)
    {
        item temp = listprint[i].info;
        printf("%-20s%-15d%-20.2f%-30s\n", temp.model, temp.memory, temp.screen_size, temp.price);
    }
}
int main()
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("phoneDB.txt", "r");
    int maxlines = countlines(fp);
    fclose(fp);
    node *phonelist = (node *) malloc(maxlines*5*sizeof(node));
    int choice = 0;
    do
    {
        FILE *fptxt = fopen("phoneDB.txt", "r");
        printf("1. Import from Text\n3. Display List\n8. Quit\n");
        printf("Your choice: ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        getchar();
        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1:
                if(isempty(fptxt))
                {
                    printf("This file is empty\n");
                    goto x;
                }
                phonelist = builldbytext(fptxt, maxlines);
                x: break;
            case 3:
                tranverse(head, maxlines);
                break;
        }
    fclose(fptxt);
    }while(choice != 8);
    free(phonelist);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is my text file (phoneDB.txt):

```
Iphone6 12 9.6 2000000
IphoneX 32 12.3 40000000
SamsungA6 16 11.3 1000000
SamsungNote6 16 12.3 12000000
Iphone5 32 9.5 6000000
Iphone5s 32 9.5 7000000
Iphone6 32 9.3 8000000
Iphone6s 32 11.3 8500000
OppoF5 32 9.3 10000000
OppoE6 32 11.3 20000000
OppoReno 16 12.6 20000000
IphoneSXmax 128 11.3 45000000
Huawei4 64 11.3 20000000
NokiaE5 16 8.6 3000000
SamsungGalaxy 32 12.3 6000000
SamsungNote7 32 12.3 8000000
Iphone7s 32 12.3 10000000
Huawei6 16 9.5 15000000
SamsungNote5 16 8.5 12500000
IphoneX 16 12.3 25000000
Iphone7 24 11.5 25100000
```

My problem: When I debug my program, I see that my program can't read the text file. It shows that the file is empty (function **isempty()** returns true). However, when I run my program, it does not show any messages (I use gcc of MinGW on Windows 10 as a compiler). Moreover, because of its unreadability, the output does not show the expected result.

When I use **ftell()** function to check the position of pointer, it returns 0.

Note: I have checked my input file name so the error is not there. I think it is somewhere else.
The output:

```
Model               Memory (GB)    Screen size (Inch)  Price
Iphone7             24             11.50               25100000
                    0              0.00
                    -2147479552    0.00
                    0              0.00
                    0              -0.42               ¨‰
                    917518         0.00                
                    0              0.00
\\Very long after that but I just show a sample of it
```

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Ok I will change it. But I think it is not the problem I got

Comment: "function isempty() returns true". Show that code. In fact, please ensure you provide a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). "Note: I have checked my input file name so the error is not there". You should check it in the program itself by checking the return value of `fopen`.

Comment: Should always check that `fopen()` succeeds

Comment: @kaylum Yes, I have edited my source code. you can check, pls

Comment: `goto x` ?? Just use an `else` !!!

Comment: @John3136 Yeah. I see your point. I just show as short as possible so I choose the important part in my source code to show to you.

Comment: Your `isempty` function name is confusing. That doesn't check for empty file. It checks whether `fopen` succeeded or not. `fopen` never fails because the file is empty. Call `perror` when `fopen` fails to see more detailed reason for error.

Comment: @kaylum My teacher teaches me that if my file pointer return NULL (fopen return NULL) it means that it does not read anything or the file is empty. I think that I don't need to use perror()

Comment: @HoangNam disregard -- you are sending in a newly allocated node as `listin` and the check on `NULL` is a check on whether the allocation succeeds, not whether the list is empty. I apologize for the confusion. (`result` from `builldbytext()`)

Comment: Your teacher is wrong or you misunderstood. Read the [fopen man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html) yourself: "Otherwise, NULL is returned and errno is set to indicate the error.". The "errno" reference means you should call `perror` to get the error string. How can NULL possibly mean "does not read anything" because `fread` is the one that reads not `fopen`.

Comment: @kaylum OK but can you help me to use **perror()** ro check the error of my program? I haven't used it yet so I don't know how to use it properly in my program

Comment: If you don't know how to call a function then read its man page. Here is the [perror man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html). Just call `perror("fopen failed");` if `fopen` returns NULL.

Comment: @kaylum I don't know why but my compiler does not show neither the **perror()** message nỏ **printf()** message when the pointer file **fopen()** return NULL.

Comment: Well perhaps it is not NULL or you changed the code in the wrong way. If it is NULL as you said from the beginning then it should at least show `printf("This file is empty\n");`.

Comment: @kaylum But as I have said, when I debug it show that messages. That is quite confusing

Comment: when asking a question about some problem with your code, post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem.  This includes code that cleanly compiles.  The posted code does not compile.  First thing we notice is the necessary `#include` statements for the needed header files are missing

Comment: regarding: *I don't know why but my compiler does not show neither the perror() message nỏ printf() message when the pointer file fopen() return NULL.*   the compiler will never show such a message.  When executing the code ( after compiling/linking the code ) if the call to `fopen()` fails, such that the code executes the function: `perror()`, then the resulting output will be to `stderr`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Much of the confusion comes from the awkward way you are approaching building your list. Set aside the menu for now -- that is left to you, let's just concentrate on building your linked list. For starters, it's impossible to tell where your failure arises because you fail to ***check the return*** of your input function. You cannot use any input function correctly (or any function critical to the continued operation of your code) unless you **check the return**. You also do not want to *Hardcode Filenames*, that is what the parameters to `int main (int argc, char **argv)` are there for — or you can take the filename to read as user-input.

Next, since your data is arranged in lines-of-input in your file, you should use a *line-oriented* input function to read from the file (such as `fgets()` or POSIX `getline()`) That way you ensure you consume an entire line of input each time and what remains unread does not depend on the format specifier used. Instead, declare a character array of sufficient size to hold each line from your file and then read into that array with `fgets()` and then separate into `name`, `mem`, `size`, and `price` using `sscanf()` (don't forget to check the return)

While you can send your open `FILE*` pointer to `builldbytext()` to read and build your list, below let's just take a simple approach and read from the file in a loop in `main()` and fill a temporary struct with the values from each line. Then we can pass the address of the pointer to your list along with a pointer to the temporary struct containing data to an `add()` function (your `push()`) to build the list.

You didn't provide your node definition, so for purposes of the example we will use:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NAMSZ  32       /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define MAXC 1024

typedef struct node_t {     /* list node */
    char name[NAMSZ];
    double size;
    int mem, price;
    struct node_t *next;
} node_t;
```

While you can use *forward-chaining* to add the nodes, you will end up with your nodes in the reverse order from what you have in the file. You can either use a *head* and *tail* pointer to add in order using the *tail* pointer in the same O(1) time or you can iterate to the end and add in O(n) time.

A simple example of adding the node at the end iterating each time would be:

```
 /** add node at end of list */
node_t *add (node_t **head, node_t *tmp)
{
    node_t **ppn = head,                    /* pointer to pointer to head */
            *pn = *head,                    /* pointer to head */
            *node = malloc (sizeof *node);  /* allocate new node */

    if (!node) {                            /* validate allocation */
        perror ("malloc-node");
        return NULL;
    }
    *node = *tmp;                           /* assign tmp struct values */
    node->next = NULL;                      /* set next pointer NULL */

    while (pn) {                            /* iterate to end of list */ 
        ppn = &pn->next;
        pn = pn->next;
    }

    return *ppn = node;                     /* assign & return new node */
}
```

(**note:** by using a *pointer-to-pointer* there is no special treatment required for adding the first or subsequent nodes)

A simple traversal `prn()` and a function to delete all nodes in the list `del_list()` when done could be:

```
/** print all nodes in list */
void prn (node_t *l)
{
    if (!l) {
        puts ("list-empty");
        return;
    }
    for (node_t *n = l; n; n = n->next)
        printf ("%-16s %3d %5g %d\n", n->name, n->mem, n->size, n->price);
}

/** delete all nodes in list */
void del_list (node_t *l)
{
    node_t *n = l;
    while (n) {
        node_t *victim = n;
        n = n->next;
        free (victim);
    }
}
```

Finally, all that is needed to take your filename to read as the first argument to the program, or read from `stdin` if no argument is provided, to fill the list and then traverse and free all allocated memory could be:

```
int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char buf[MAXC];         /* buffer to hold each line */
    node_t *list = NULL;    /* pointer to list (must initialize NULL) */
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }

    while (fgets (buf, MAXC, fp)) {     /* read each line from file */
        node_t tmp;                     /* temporary struct to hold values */
        /* if name, mem, size, price successfully parsed from line */
        if (sscanf (buf, "%s %d %lf %d",
                    tmp.name, &tmp.mem, &tmp.size, &tmp.price) == 4)
            if (!(add (&list, &tmp)))   /* add node to list/validate */
                break;
    }
    if (fp != stdin)   /* close file if not stdin */
        fclose (fp);

    prn (list);
    del_list (list);
}
```

(**note:** the `is_empty()` functionality is handled in each function that receives the list simply by validating that the first node in the list isn't `NULL`)

**Example Use/Output**

With your data in the file `dat/phones.txt`, you would receive:

```
$ ./bin/lls_phones dat/phones.txt
Iphone6           12   9.6 2000000
IphoneX           32  12.3 40000000
SamsungA6         16  11.3 1000000
SamsungNote6      16  12.3 12000000
Iphone5           32   9.5 6000000
Iphone5s          32   9.5 7000000
Iphone6           32   9.3 8000000
Iphone6s          32  11.3 8500000
OppoF5            32   9.3 10000000
OppoE6            32  11.3 20000000
OppoReno          16  12.6 20000000
IphoneSXmax      128  11.3 45000000
Huawei4           64  11.3 20000000
NokiaE5           16   8.6 3000000
SamsungGalaxy     32  12.3 6000000
SamsungNote7      32  12.3 8000000
Iphone7s          32  12.3 10000000
Huawei6           16   9.5 15000000
SamsungNote5      16   8.5 12500000
IphoneX           16  12.3 25000000
Iphone7           24  11.5 25100000
```

If you had used *forward-chaining* to add the nodes, then they would print in the reverse order.

**Memory Use/Error Check**

In any code you write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed.

It is imperative that you use a memory error checking program to ensure you do not attempt to access memory or write beyond/outside the bounds of your allocated block, attempt to read or base a conditional jump on an uninitialized value, and finally, to confirm that you free all the memory you have allocated.

For Linux `valgrind` is the normal choice. There are similar memory checkers for every platform. They are all simple to use, just run your program through it.

```
$ valgrind ./bin/lls_phones dat/phones.txt
==17133== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==17133== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==17133== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==17133== Command: ./bin/lls_phones dat/phones.txt
==17133==
Iphone6           12   9.6 2000000
IphoneX           32  12.3 40000000
SamsungA6         16  11.3 1000000
SamsungNote6      16  12.3 12000000
Iphone5           32   9.5 6000000
Iphone5s          32   9.5 7000000
Iphone6           32   9.3 8000000
Iphone6s          32  11.3 8500000
OppoF5            32   9.3 10000000
OppoE6            32  11.3 20000000
OppoReno          16  12.6 20000000
IphoneSXmax      128  11.3 45000000
Huawei4           64  11.3 20000000
NokiaE5           16   8.6 3000000
SamsungGalaxy     32  12.3 6000000
SamsungNote7      32  12.3 8000000
Iphone7s          32  12.3 10000000
Huawei6           16   9.5 15000000
SamsungNote5      16   8.5 12500000
IphoneX           16  12.3 25000000
Iphone7           24  11.5 25100000
==17133==
==17133== HEAP SUMMARY:
==17133==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==17133==   total heap usage: 24 allocs, 24 frees, 6,848 bytes allocated
==17133==
==17133== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==17133==
==17133== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==17133== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Always confirm that you have freed all memory you have allocated and that there are no memory errors.

Look things over and let me know if you have questions. If you would like to change to *forward-chaining* or using a `tail` pointer, let me know and I'm happy to help further.

Comment: Although your program can read (I haven't checked it yet), your answer does not base on my problem. If you have read problem above, you will see that there exists a opposition between my compiler and debugger. While my debugger does show the error message when ``!fp`` is true, my compiler does not shows anything, just runs and shows an unexpected output. Have you ever thought about it? I really need an explanation

Comment: What compiler are you using? This is generic C without anything non-standard used. It ill compile and run on any compiler. If you are using an old-old compiler that only provides C89/90, then we just need to take the declaration of the loop variables out of the loops -- that's simple enough. What errors did you receive. This code should compile and run without a single warning. Also let me know what OS you are on

Comment: I have compiled this on gcc, and an old VS (the MS Developers Toolkit for Win7 (other than changing the loop variables to old define before variables, it compiled and works find on VS.

Comment: Maybe there is something wrong with my gdb. Anyway. my code run well now. Thanks for your answer.