# Struggling to understand why this is not printing out

Tags: c, linked-list

I have a piece of code here where I want to place a node at the end of a linked list. This is my code along with the main statement and other important information.

```
    typedef struct node
    {
        char fName[maxName];
        char lname[maxName];
        char PUID[maxID];
        char age[maxAge];
        struct node *next;
    }node;

    node *head = NULL;//used to store the address of the first node

node * createNode()
{
    node *temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));


    printf("Enter the first name: ");
    scanf("%s", temp -> fName);

    printf("Enter the last name: ");
    scanf("%s", temp -> lname);

    printf("Enter the PUID: ");
    scanf("%s", temp -> PUID);

    printf("Enter the Age: ");
    scanf("%s", temp -> age);


    return temp;

}
    void insertEnd(node *newNode)
    {
        node *current = NULL;
        current = head;

        if(current -> next != NULL)
        {
            current = current -> next;

        }


        current -> next = newNode;
        current -> next = NULL; 

    }
    int main()
    {
        char fName[maxName];
        char lName[maxName];
        char PUID[maxID];
        char age[maxAge];


        /*node *newNode = createNode();
        createListNode(newNode);
        node *insertNodeFront = createNode();
        insertFront(insertNodeFront);
        node *insertMiddleNode = createNode();
        insertMiddle(insertMiddleNode);*/
        node *insertEndNode = createNode();
        insertEnd(insertEndNode);
        displayList();

        return 0;
    }
```

I am having the problem when I try to run the code it takes the necessary inputs, but then nothing is printed out in my linked list. What am I doing wrong? Any help would be welcomed.

Comment: Your code invokes *undefined behavior*. The initial insertion performs `if(current -> next != NULL)` when `current` is `NULL`.  That dereference, therefore, is UB. The line prior, `current= head;` is assigning `NULL` to `current`. You need to setup `head` correctly on initial insertion when the list is empty.

Comment: [Can not read text file in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61166837/can-not-read-text-file-in-c/61167245#61167245) may help.

Answer (score 0):

You ran constantly below two statements:

```
current -> next = newNode;
current -> next = NULL;
```

It would output nothing because the code finally set the node to NULL